# Perl cgi bind dynamic number of columns

Tags: perl, cgi, dbi

I'm trying to make a simple select from a database, the thing is that I want the same script to be able to select any of the tables in it. I have gotten everything solved up until the point when I need to bind the columns to variables, since they must be generated dynamically I just don't know how to do it.

here's the code:

```
 if($op eq "SELECT"){
    if ($whr){
    $query1 = "SELECT $colsf FROM $tab WHERE $whr";
    }else{
    $query1 = "SELECT $colsf FROM $tab";
    }
    $seth = $dbh->prepare($query1);
    $seth->execute();
    foreach $cajas(@columnas){
    $seth->bind_col(*$dynamically_generated_var*);
    }
    print $q->br();
    print $q->br();
    print $q->br();
```

The variable `@columans` contains the name of the selected columns (which varies a lot), and I need a variable assigned for each of the columns on the `$seth->bind_col()`.

How can I acheive this?

Comment: `bind_col()` complicates things here and doesn't really gain you anything; the `fetchrow_*()` methods are better suited to this kind of problem.
By the way, be careful with that SQL or users can do all kinds of nasty things with that query. You have to sanitize every bit of data you put into `$colsf` from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bind_col` will not gain you anything here. As you have already figured out, that's used to *bind a fixed number of results to a set of variables*. But you **do not have a fixed set**.

Thinking in terms of *oh, I can just create them dynamically* is a very common mistake. It will get you [into all kinds of trouble later](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). Perl has a data structure specifically for this use case: **the hash**.

DBI has a bunch of functions built in for retrieving data after `execute`. One of those is [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref). It will return the results as a hash reference, with one key per column, one row at a time.

```
while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  p $res; # p is from Data::Printer
}
```

Let's assume the result looks like this:

```
$res = {
  id => 1,
  color => 'red',
}
```

You can access the color by saying `$res->{color}`. The perldocs on [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) have a lot of info about this.

Note that the best practice for naming statement handle variables is `$sth`.

In your case, you have a dynamic number of columns. Those have to be joined to be in the format of `col1, col2, col3`. I guess you have already done that in `$colsf`. The table is pretty obvious in `$tab`, so we only have the `$whr` left.

This part is tricky. It's important to [always sanitize your input](https://xkcd.com/327/), **especially in a CGI environment**. With DBI this is best done by using *placeholders*. They will take care of all the escaping for you, and they are easy to use.

```
my $sth = $dbi->prepare('select cars from garage where color=?');
$sth->execute($color);
```

Now we don't need to care if the color is `red`, `blue` or `' and 1; --`, which might have broken stuff. If it's all very dynamic, use [`$dbi->quote`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#quote) instead.

Let's put this together in your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# ...

# the columns
my $colsf = join ',', @some_list_of_column_names; # also check those!

# the table name
my $table = $q->param('table');
die 'invalid table name' if $table =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/; # input checking

# where
# I'm skipping this part as I don't know where it is comming from

if ($op eq 'SELECT') {
  my $sql = 'SELECT $colsf FROM $table';
  $sql .= ' WHERE $whr' if $whr;

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbi->errstr;
  $sth->execute;

  my @headings = $sth->{NAME}; # see https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#NAME1
  while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
    # do stuff here
  }
}
```